# Converting numpy array (image) to pdf base64

Tags: numpy, opencv, base64

I have an image, represented as a numpy array.

I want to avoid writing it out as a pdf, and then reading the file back to get the base64 representation of the file, is there an easier way to do this without writing a file?

- My goal is to have the base64 representation of the output pdf file (without outputting one)

If I understand correctly, the base64 encoding is different for jpgs and pdfs, is this correct?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PIL `Image.fromarray` function, one could convert all the images to PIL images.

Then again using PIL, `save()` could be used to save the images together as a PDF and write them to a buff:

```
buff = io.BytesIO()

pil_images[0].save(buff, "PDF", resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=pil_images[1:])
```

`buff.getvalue()` returns the bytes (which is good enough for me, but it is also still possible to get the base64 representation)